# Условная отрисовка при React + Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, spa

Есть типичное SPA на react + redux.
Внутри него есть несколько различных view.
Redux-store представляет из себя огромную помойку.

Есть некая верхняя компонента MainView
И у неё в рендере примерно следующее

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <View1 />
      <View2 />
    </div>
  );
}
```

View1 и View2 отрисовываются условно и меняются друг с другом местами.
Каждая view берет данные для себя из своего подхранилища:
ну т.е.

```
store = {
  view1: {
    active: false,
    // ...
  },
  view2: {
    active: true,
    // ...
  }
}
```

В каждом таком подхранилище View* еще куча мусора (т.е. данных) которые обновляются довольно активно, чем вызывают постоянный перерендеринг компоненты.

А теперь вопрос, как лучше сделать условную отрисовку этих компонент?
Вариант 1: взять значения `active` для обоих View* внутри MainView и сделать:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      { isView1Active && <View1 /> }
      { isView2Active && <View2 /> }
    </div>
  );
}
```

Вариант 2: внутри каждой View* компоненты сделать

```
render() {
  { active } = this.props;

  if (!active) return null;

  //...
}
```

Какой вариант лучше? И почему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оба варианта рабочие. По производительности тоже одинаковы. Так что особо разницы нет. НО! Условный рендеринг - это дополнительная логика, которую не стоит зашивать внутри компонента. Я бы выбрал первый вариант, так как сразу видно что есть два компонента, которые отрисовываются по какому-то условию (то есть может отрисоваться один или вообще ни одного). Это будет не совсем прозрачно, если спрятать логику внутри.

Comment: https://medium.com/@cowi4030/optimizing-conditional-rendering-in-react-3fee6b197a20 вот также можешь почитать по теме